# Cakephp E-mail Connection Office365

Tags: cakephp, office365

I have problem with sending emails using CakePhp and Office365 SMTP server

My configuration in cakephp looks so

```
'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Smtp',
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'smtp.office365.com',
            'port' => 587,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'username' => 'email',
            'password' => 'pass',
            'client' => null,
            'tls' => true,
            'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
        ],
    ],
```

I am getting the following error message:

Connection timed out
Cake\Network\Exception\SocketException

Settings for Office365 are here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/POP-and-IMAP-settings-for-Outlook-Office-365-for-business-7fc677eb-2491-4cbc-8153-8e7113525f6c

I have tried with timeout to 60 secs, port 25, and with tls:// prefix but it is the same error.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a firewall problem to me.

Comment: Thx for helping, but problem is solved. I have used class Name -> Smtp... If I use "'className' => 'Mail'" then works...

Comment: @JohnWayne wow man, I've read dozens of answers, tried every combination possible of TLS, SSL, and issued a ticket to the hosting service. In cake 2.5, I decided to change `'transport' => 'Smtp'` to `'transport' => 'Mail'`and it worked!. This was my final search attempt: "cakephp 2.5 outlook" instead of searching for the specific error. Thanks!